# Is there a way to view the ECDH Shared Secret generated within microsoft CNG?

Tags: encryption, encryption-asymmetric, diffie-hellman, cng

I am trying to perform a ECDH key exchange between MS CNG and another device.  In order to debug things, I would like to see what shared secret is being generated in CNG so i can compare it with the secret generated by my other device. Anybody know of a way to do this?

Comment: Did you end up solving this?  The closest thing I could come up with is writing your own CNG provider that implements an "identity" hash... However that requires being an admin and placing a binary in system32, I'm looking for another way.

Comment: Seems like the best way is to use a third-party solution instead of the MS crypto stuff.  I've noticed CAPI/WinCrypt is similarly limited.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at CNG documentation at MSDN: [NCryptSecretAgreement function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The [same function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298399.aspx) is accessible from .NET.

Comment: This gives you a handle, not the actual session key.  `NCryptDeriveKey` can give you a hash of it but not the actual value.  The question unanswered here is how to retrieve the value.